# How to give the image path in the check box field option for a content type

Tags: 7, entities, media

I am creating a checkbox field in my content type and I want images to be displayed as checkboxes option.

In Drupal 7, there is a feature to add images as field list, but I am unable to give the full path for that image.

See the below screenshot for better understanding.
[image]

I cannot give my image path as http://localhost/sites/default/.. because the base path changes when we move to the Production. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

Your image path needs a `/` before `sites`. Should be `"/sites/default/files/test-image1.jpg"`

If you don't have a `/` at the start, then it appends your url code to whatever page you're on. Example: `node/1/sites/default/files/test-image1.jpg` which is not what you want (broken image since it doesn't exist)